# How to secure a WCF service to be consumed by a specific application only?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, security

I have a specific Silverlight application, that is fed with data by a WCF-Service. I want to make sure, that the WCF-Service is only called by **that specific** Silverlight App. What is the best way to accomplish that and what do I have to do? It doesn't have to be a high security solution.

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable basic authentication (username/password) on the service. Create a single user which the Silverlight app will use to authenticate itself with the service.

Easier, but less secure, might be to just use some sort of identifier (only known to the Silverlight client) as a service parameter.

Both options are obviously most secure when implemented with HTTPS. This can be accomplished by using a server certificate.

Comment: The problem with the approach is that the key/password is not secure. Be it flash/silverlight or javascript, the key can easily be extracted from it.

Comment: Right, good point. In the case of javascript etc, there is no way to do this programatically in a 100% secure way. So, that might mean you're you're stuck with something like client certificates or IP based filtering in your web server/firewall, possibly combined with the solution mentioned above.

Comment: 100% security is an illusion anyway :)
It is just "how much effort and skill does it take to get around the security restrictions". So it depends on the importance of the data. A username/password authentication will do it for me, thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 1):

You **CANNOT** restrict access to such a service. Your app will need access to whatever key/password you chose. It is trivial to decompile your app and extract the key. SSL/TLS will not help - because the password can be extracted from the compiled code.

This question has been asked quite a few times recently -

1. [Ensure exclusive access to webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616797/ensure-exclusive-access-to-webservice)
2. [How to restrict access to my web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578645/how-to-restrict-access-to-my-web-service)
3. [How can I create and use a web service in public but still restrict its use to only my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601805/how-can-i-create-and-use-a-web-service-in-public-but-still-restrict-its-use-to-on)

Answer (score 1):

If your application is running anonymously then it's virtually impossible to be 100% secure.

How ever if your are requiring your users to authenticate then you should be able to make the service relatively secure by requiring their login credentials...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it easy with WCF, but I guess you could do something using client certificates. I only used this approach for protecting websites and it was quite easy to do...